# Is data in WinJS.Binding.List persistent?

Tags: microsoft-metro

I'm new to windows 8 metro style app development and I come from `PHP` based web application development background.

Now, in my app I fetch data using `WinJS.xhr` and add it to `WinJS.Binding.List` list. The problem is when I revisit the page, the old data acquired from the previous xhr code is still there and the new data appends to this list.

How to rectify this?

### EDIT

Homedeliverydata.js file

```
     var list = new WinJS.Binding.List();
        var groupedItems = list.createGrouped(
            function groupKeySelector(item) { return item.group.key; },
            function groupDataSelector(item) { return item.group; }
        );

        function getFeaturedRestaurants(city_id) {
            Utilities.featuredRestaurants(city_id, 'home_delivery').
                then(function onComplete(result) {
                    var restaurants = result.result;

                    for (var i = 0; i < restaurants.length; i++) {
                        restaurants[i].group = Groups[0];
                        restaurants[i].key = restaurants[i].id;
                        list.push(restaurants[i]);
                    }
                },
                function onError() {
                }, function onProgress() {
                });
        }
  function clearData() {
        list.splice(0, list.length);
        list._currentKey = 0;
    }
```

HomeDelivery.js

```
  ready: function (element, options) {
            //code above this line removed
           HomeDeliveryListdata.GetSearchData(params).then(afterCall, function (req) { }, function (req) { });

        },
 unload: function () {
            HomeDeliveryListdata.clearData();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list will last the lifetime of the variable it is being assigned to.  In addition, if you are using the single page model for you app (the default, recommended way), then the variable containing the list will likely survive from page to page.

If you want the existing list to be replaced each time you visit a page, make sure that you are scoping the lifetime of the list appropriately (usually scoping the list to the success promise of the xhr request is sufficient) or writing code to clear and refresh the list.

Hard to point out the exact fix without example code, but hopefully that will help you fix the problem.

Comment: Brand. Please see the edited question. I have added the code. My app is a single page app. Currently, I'm clearing the list when page is unloaded. Please tell me whether this is the correct way to do or not. Thanks

Comment: If I was going to just mod your code "as is", I would declare the list variable as "var list;" and then in getFeaturedRestaurants I would recreate the list each time I called the function - list = new WinJS.Binding.List().  That way you have no need to dispose of the list when the page unloads.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish it to be available between different WinJS.Navigations, then you should **not** be clearing the data; just hold on to the variable somewhere within your application, and when you need it again, just re-use it as a data source.

*However* it will not persist between executions of your application (e.g. if it's terminated). To do that you will need to write the data to the disk using either [files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464978.aspx) or a [database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441274.aspx) (mozilla has a [good guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB), and theres a nice wrapper [here](https://github.com/grork/db.js))